# How to find the parent element from set of rows

Tags: sql, parent, rows

I have a set of data as:

```
 a b c
 d c 
 e d 
 c g 
 f a 
 v w 
 v m 
 n m o
```

From these data I need to group

```
{ a b c d e f g}    
{ m o v w }
```

without much iteration through the data set. Is it possible with high level SQL functions or some easy method in HIVE/PIG(Just a guess)?

Comment: "*or some easy method in HIVE*" -  Does this mean you use Hive?

Comment: Actually supposed to use Netezza.But if in hive or some new data approach  is having solution I will switch to that.

Comment: All modern DBMS have support for recursive queries. The SQL standard defines "recursive common table expressions" to do that. I don't know Netezza, maybe it does support that as well.

Comment: Hi, We may be having 1-10 million records .So if we have a solution  which is having minimum recursion that will be great.I am not aware of Map reduce concept.I think those key value pair approach will more appropriate

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is to find each connected sub-graphs in your graphs of all nodes.
You can solve it by first constructing the graph, then going through all nodes seeking for connected sub-graphs.

To build your "big" graph, each node is a letter and two letters are linked together if they belong to the same set.

Then go for each letter, try to navigate through the graph starting with this letter and eliminating each letter you see. The time you relaunch your search algorithm is the number of set you have.

Considering the complexity, the graph construction depends on the number of set you have as well as the number of different letters.
For graph search, it is linear with your number of letters and connections.
Of course, depending on how your set are given and the data structure you use you can make some optimisation.

More information on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)#Algorithms).